# Working with old version of KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I had developed a complex enough canvas web application using `kinetic.js` about a year ago. I used `kinetic.js` **3.10.4. version** And I'm surprised that my application is not work anymore on the latest Browser like Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. For example, there was an error while creating `Text` shapes. Here is the stack trace error from Google Chrome debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error
Kinetic.Shape.Kinetic.Node.extend.fill
config.drawFunc
Kinetic.Shape.Kinetic.Node.extend._draw
Kinetic.Container.Kinetic.Node.extend._drawChildren
Kinetic.Layer.Kinetic.Container.extend._draw
Kinetic.Layer.Kinetic.Container.extend.draw
loadMenu
_background.onload
```

I've tried using **4.6.0 version** but there are some deprecated functions and features on my legacy code. 
I just wondering that I could using my current **3.10.4 version** library (with several effortless fix) rather than update to the **4.6.0 version**. Is it still possible to do that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which deprecated functions are you needing?  My experience is that Kinetic often adds functionality and often moves methods, but rarely eliminates functionality.   Check Kinetic's changelog to see if your needed functions have simple 4.6 counterparts: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log

Comment: I got the `.transitionTo` methods is not working anymore.
The current (3.10.4) `Text Shapes` `.fill` attributes is not working and causing `Uncaught TypeError` on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Transitions are eliminated and have been replaced by Tweens effective KineticV4.5.

Tweens are coded similarly to the old Transitions.

So any recoding of Transitions into Tweens should be straight-forward.

Changes in ChromeV26 broke kinetic fills--so KineticV4.3 and older fills won't work.

Possible options:

- Try Kinetic version 4.4 where fills are fixed and transitions still exist.
- Recode your Transtions into Tweens and use the current version.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm realized that `.fill` attribute used by `KineticJS` was broken by Google Chrome earlier version. It used to be `.fill(context)` but now it's just `.fill()` without parameters. But how come those code not supported by Google Chrome anymore? Isn't it a standard from W3C? Does any standards changed by them? Thanks :)